# MySQL WHERE: how to write "!=" or "not equals"?

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I need to do this

```
DELETE FROM konta WHERE taken != ''
```

But != doesn't exist in mysql.
Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM konta WHERE taken <> '';
```

Answer (score 46):

The [!= operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal) most certainly does exist! It is an alias for the standard `<>` operator.

Perhaps your fields are not actually empty strings, but instead `NULL`?

To compare to `NULL` you can use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` or the [null safe equals operator `<=>`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to).

Comment: Eh, I can see where the `NULL` is going (+1), but it seems odd to want to delete *not empty* or NULL ..

Answer (score 13):

You may be using old version of Mysql but surely you can use

```
 DELETE FROM konta WHERE taken <> ''
```

But there are many other options available. You can try the following ones

```
DELETE * from konta WHERE strcmp(taken, '') <> 0;

DELETE * from konta where NOT (taken = '');
```