# PHP/MySQL - Error when using SELECT but no matching data

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the ID of an image that is boostAmount-boostStart>total.  Currently if an image exists that is appropriate it works.  However, if there is nothing appropriate to show I get this error.

> Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1' at line 1

```
$photoToGuess = mysql_query("SELECT photoID,id,total,boostStart,boostAmount,auth,photoUploadDate FROM photos WHERE (boostAmount !=0) AND ((boostAmount-boostStart)>total) AND (auth=2 OR auth=5 OR auth=7) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1") or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
$getphotoToGuess = mysql_fetch_array($photoToGuess);

    //Yes
    if(mysql_num_rows($photoToGuess) > 0)
    {
    //do something
    }
```

Comment: missing one `)` at  before ORDER BY

Comment: Your Query Syntax is correct....you need to debug your code and update your full stack trace...

Comment: Even when I remove ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 it shows the same error. Which seems really weird to me.

Comment: change your != to <>

use this as a reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421741/mysql-where-how-to-write-or-not-equals

Comment: changing your != to <> does not help :( but i appreciate this was wrong

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I removed die condition you can achieve die condition using if statement...It is working fine chech once.

```
$photoToGuess = mysql_query("SELECT photoID,id,total,boostStart,boostAmount,auth,photoUploadDate FROM photos WHERE (boostAmount !=0) AND ((boostAmount-boostStart)>total) AND (auth=2 OR auth=5 OR auth=7) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
$getphotoToGuess = mysql_fetch_array($photoToGuess);

//Yes
    if(mysql_num_rows($photoToGuess) > 0)
    {
    //do something
    }
```

You can refer this http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 1):

Your if condition is wrong
    why are you using `$photoToGuess` in your if conditioner code here

```
if(mysql_num_rows($getphotoToGuess ) > 0){
    // do something
}
```

Comment: This IF condition works if there is a result to show.  The error is when there is no matching result in the database.

Comment: (boostAmount !=0) AND ((boostAmount-boostStart)>total) AND (auth=2 OR auth=5 OR auth=7) what is exactly you want to checked using this statment there is something wrong with your AND statment checked once again and clearly u miss the one closing bracket in  above mention query

Comment: you r query is not working because in your where condition it will get wrong value which is either 1 or 0 so your condition is working like this       "from where photos 0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"

Comment: @user2203466 start removing conditions one-by-one and check which condition is giving problem.

Comment: ((boostAmount-boostStart)>total)

Gives the issue.

Comment: For reference
(boostAmount-boostStart>total)

IF figures are 

200 - 0 > 200 (finds no results, gives error)
199 - 0 > 200 (works)

Comment: used >= instead of only '>'